# remotely waking arduino from sleep

Tags: arduino, at-command

I have an arduino uno connected to a sim800l. I want to know if it is possible to wake up the arduino from sleep mode(AT+CSCLK=2 method) using a text or only through a serial monitor. I would also be  open any other solutions. I have read a few sites on the AT+CSCLK=2 command but I'm still unsure how to call the command if anyone could help by giving code examples of how to use it or provide links I would appreciate it.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to wake up, if the Arduino then the AT command is irrelevant, if the SIM800 then use AT+CSCLK=0

Comment: You can for sure wakeup the SIM800L from sleep, and there are several ways to do it. I would write an answer about it but, as @Nino said, it is not clear how modem's sleep mode should intereact with arduino. We could give you some pieces of advice, but it would be too general, as many choices depend to the way the two devices are connected.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I apologize that its so vague. My knowledge of arduino sleep is limited. I have a arduino with an ultrasonic sensor  and the sim800l module. This has to be able to measure the level of a water tank on command. The problem is these tanks will be mostly remote so will have to be powered by battery and solar. What I'm looking for is a way to conserve energy while it is not in use but it should still be able wake up remotely using text ideally. I was under the impression the AT+CSCLK=2  command would put the arduino and the sim800l to sleep

Comment: No, only the modem device. In order to have both in sleep you'll have to design your program accordingly

Comment: SIM800L as a 3G module doesn't have the capability to wake up a host. In order to do that, try to replace it with an NB-IoT module such as SIM7020/7080. Under the NB-IoT spec, there is a Power Saving Mode (PSM), PSM is a device mode in which the unit can signal to the network that it will “sleep” for a while. Having that mode the device saves battery cycles from attaching/detaching from the network. The network itself also knows when and where (in which base station) to keep the device active. It also has a hardware pin that can be used to trigger the wakeup of Arduino.

Comment: @hcheung something can be done with a 3G device too. But Arduino Application has to be designed "around" this need.